# How to see if there are 3 consecutive (in a row) Rs in my program?

Tags: java

I have a project that will randomly produce 2 letters (E and R). When there are 3 letters of R, the program will stop and print the final random string and, "There are 3 Rs!"

I was able to make the for-loop, etc. But, there is an error saying, "String index out of range". I can't put spaces in the string when I first declare it (my teacher wants it inline with the output). Thanks for the help.

Here is what I got:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String eOrR = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 2147483647; i++){
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
        if (random == 2){
            eOrR += "E";
        }else{
            eOrR += "R";
        }

        if(eOrR.charAt(i) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i+1) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i+2) == 'R'){
            System.out.println(eOrR + "\nThree R's in a row!");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No because she won't answer it. My friends don't know how to do it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nicer way to handle your logic is to maintain a counter for how many `R` letters you have seen.  This counter will be incremented by one each time an `R` is seen, and will be reset to zero upon seeing an `E`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String eOrR = "";
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < 2147483647; i++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);

        if (random == 2) {
            eOrR += "E";
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            eOrR += "R";
            ++counter;
        }

        if (counter >= 3) {
            System.out.println(eOrR + "\nThree R's in a row!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this even more efficient, you could put the second `if` statement inside the `else` block. It should also use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), because concatenation in a loop is slow.

Comment: @4castle I won't make that change, but a change worth making would be to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.  I suspect though that this might be out of scope for the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because , the first time the loop runs,

```
if(eOrR.charAt(i) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i+1) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i+2) == 'R'){
    System.out.println(eOrR + "\nThree R's in a row!");
    break;
}
```

the above code is called and there wont even be 3 characters to check because you added only one that is `E` or `R` .
To fix this, call the above code after checking if `string.lenght()` is at leat `3` characters.

Comment: Okay. I'll try! Thanks!  -Edit: I still get an out of bounds error:

Comment: It also needs to be `i-1` and `i-2`. If `i` represents the last character in the string, then it would need to check the characters behind it.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. But I still get a out of bounds error.  `if(eOrR.length() >= 3){
                if(eOrR.charAt(i-1) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i) == 'R' && eOrR.charAt(i+1) == 'R'){
                    System.out.println(eOrR + "\nThree R's in a row!");
                    break;
                }
            }` @4castle

Comment: @FusionPointInc It won't work if you put `i+anything`. If `i` is the last character in the string, there can't be anything after it. There's nothing after the last index. It must be `charAt(i)`, `charAt(i-1)`, and `charAt(i-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), and pass as parameter the string to be found (in this case RRR); if this is not found the method return an integer (-1)

## Example:

```
if(eOrR.indexOf("RRR")!=-1) {
    System.out.println(eOrR + "\nThree R's in a row!");
}
```

Comment: That's really inefficient. It only needs to look at the last 3 character in the string. This would make an O(1) operation become O(n)

Comment: I never really used the method before. But I will try it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

=Take a look at your second if conditional block.

Now, pay particular attention to the setup of your parameter. I'd recommend getting a piece of paper and creating an array of 4 characters (e.g. [W,W,R,R]).

Run through the array using your 2nd if conditional block and make sure you keep in mind that the '&&'s are subroutine–build upon–to the 'if' routine.

If you notice, your println function will not even get called.

Comment: I never really used the method before. But I will try it!